# Name of a book about jet powered blood sucking insects from the 80's

Tags: aliens, story-identification

Looking for a book from the 80's about alien jet powered blood sucking insects. The insects were able to kill a human by sucking their blood ultra fast. I thought it was an awesome book and I’m trying to get another copy.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] some more stuff in? For example, more details on plot points would help a lot.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115973/in-what-story-do-bird-sized-flying-insects-threaten-the-survival-of-the-human-po

Answer (score 6):

Possibly... '*Earth Has Been Found*' (also known as 'Xeno') by D. F. Jones. (1979) Synopsis from [Book Barbarian](http://bookbarbarian.com/earth-has-been-found-by-d-f-jones/):

> From a world far beyond our own, the ultimate invasion is here.
>
> Earth has been found by a horde of creatures that not even the wildest imagination could invent – sinister parasitic creatures that took to their human hosts with deadly speed and bloodthirsty precision.
>
> The terror that unfolds has terrifying consequences for all involved, and the invasion reveals something much more frightening and final than ever suspected.
>
> Earth Has Been Found is a gripping and chilling first contact sci fi novel, from classic science fiction author D. F. Jones.

[image: Earth has been found front cover]

I couldn't find much online, I just remembered reading it a few years ago and there was these little very fast insects - I think at the end the remnants of humanity lived underground and wore armour when they went to the surface to avoid the little beggars biting them. IIRC the people also worshipped them (?)